# using android sample project in my project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

Hi i am trying to give users an option to make Notes in my application on click of a button "Save Notes " . I really liked the android sample Notepad application . How to use it in my project . is it just copy /paste the java files and  icons and style ?

Comment: @Peshal : I have not tried anything . I am just asking that if i want to use android sample notepad exactly the way it is on click of my button ... can i just simply copy paste the files ?

Comment: Make Notepad as library project and add in your project.